# Ajax Function not collecting data from URL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using this ajax function to call a html page but it showing the following error:

```
OPTIONS file:///D:/My%20Web%20Sites/bbbb/flair/demos/url
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

```js
singlePageCallback: function (url, element) {
  var t = this;
  $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      timeout: 5000
    })
    .done(function (result) {
      t.updateSinglePage(result);
    })
    .fail(function () {
      t.updateSinglePage("Error! Please refresh the page!");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="cbp-item graphic">
  <div class="cbp-caption">
    <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
      <img src="img/gallery/thumb/1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
      <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
          <a href="ajax/project1.html" 
              class="cbp-singlePage cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft">
            <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="img/gallery/1big.jpg" 
              class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonRight" 
              data-title="Project Title"> 
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Use a web-server. Why are you using `file:///`?

Comment: @Satpal like Local host ?

Comment: Also check this-  url: 'url' (in ajax call). Dont use it as a string. It is a variable, which is passed to a function.

Comment: @ManishGupta if i m not using url as string then also this error coming.

Comment: @MayankBothra use indeed a localhost. You stay getting problems if your working local. I don't know if you have already setup a localhost but i prefer http://www.usbwebserver.net. It's very easy to start the server

Comment: @AndreasFurster Sir m already Using XXMAP :)

Comment: Ok, but why are you still using a `file:///`?